# Get value of item Subscription of observer Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have an item, I am subscribing it like this :

```
 this.databasesService.getDatabase(id)
.subscribe(
  database =>{this.item = database; console.log("In "+JSON.stringify(this.item)); } ,
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  console.log("After "+JSON.stringify(this.item));
```

Out put is like this :
[image]

Comment: Where are you displaying `After`? What is the data type of `item`?

Comment: Just after the subscribtion @DeborahK

Comment: `asynchronous` nature. `After` is not going to wait for he `service` call

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I wanted to get the value of item and I m now with using the .finally(() => { } able to get it .

Answer (score 2):

> Subscription of observer work only inside it

Right. That's how it works.

Imagine that you subscribe to a magazine. You can read the magazine only after the first issue arrives two weeks later. You cannot read the magazine immediately after subscribing, because it has not come yet.

Comment: Can I steal this metaphor for a blog post? I think we need one on this topic!

Comment: I love the way you have explained it, Big thanks :D; In fact i wanted to get the value of the inside of the observer or to now when the issue of the magazine is out. Now using .finally(() => { ...} it notify me that the issue is out.

Comment: `finally` does not notify you that an issue is out. You are notified that an issue is out, exactly, and only, by the callback you provide to the call to `subscribe`. `finally` is invoked when your subscription is **finished** (in other words, you have received all 12 issues of your annual subscription), or ends in some kind of error. For instance, `finally` might be called if the subscription had zero emissions. If might be called if the observable entered an error state before emitting anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is the order of execution of your code:

```
     this.databasesService.getDatabase(id)
  (1)    .subscribe(                                               
  (3)      database =>{this.item = database; console.log("In "+JSON.stringify(this.item)); } ,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  (2)      console.log("After "+JSON.stringify(this.item));
```

So the "After" is displaying first because it is executed first. It appears that `this.item` in this case is the previously retrieved item.

After the data is retrieved, *then* the first method passed to the subscribe method is executed (marked with (3) above). And the "In" message is displayed with the data retrieved from the service.

If you need to do something when the data is retrieved, you can do it here:

```
 this.databasesService.getDatabase(id)
.subscribe(
  database =>{
       this.item = database; 
       console.log("In "+JSON.stringify(this.item));
       // Do anything else with the `this.item` here.
  } ,
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Comment: So how could I retrieve the Item that is inside the (3)?

Comment: You have it in `this.item` ... but not until the data is retrieved. What are you trying to do with it? Maybe then we can provide a more specific suggestion for you?